# Google Local fonts in SharePoint

Tags: 2010, branding, google-fonts

Which is the recommended way to include Google Fonts in SharePoint? It must be locally because there is no access to the Internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Downloading a google font and setting up an offline site that uses it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27696481/94217)

Put the font files into you "Style Library" and reference them from there.

Don't forget to [configure Blob cache](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770229.aspx#BLOB) to make the files cachable.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. In particular for the link to https://google-webfonts-helper.herokuapp.com/. To support old browsers, I had to add the MIME WOFF in IIS as explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607560/font-face-works-in-ie8-but-not-ie9. I left my solution http://surpoint.blogspot.com.ar/2016/04/como-incluir-fuentes-de-google.html documented. hanks Peer !